# Setting up internal and external IP

Tags: networking, ssl, ip-address

I am quite new at setting websites up to contain SSL certificates and allow them through a firewall. I am currently at step one and have been told that I need to set up an internal IP address on my IIS server. I have also been advised that in order to do this I set up the IP through the network interface.

Can anyone help me figure out where the network interface is and how to create that IP address within the network interface?

Comment: Unless your IIS server isn't on the network right now, it already has an internal IP address.

Comment: Please get an expert to teach you these things and setup the system. With your expertise the server will be hacked in seconds and be a risk to the public.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Networking basics](http://serverfault.com/questions/287256/networking-basics)

Comment: Shane Madden - The IIS server is already on the network with an internal IP. I am setting up a website through IIS services but need to give it a unique IP address. How do I create an IP address to allow the site to be hosted on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "create" an IP address, you *assign* one.  You should have a list of all the IP addresses currently in use or reserved (for assignment via DHCP) in the netblock you're using for your network.  All that's needed is to select an unused IP address from that list, add it to the list (so you don't use it for something else later), and use it on your server.